# Is there a record player that plays digital music upon needle placement?

Tags: vinyl, record

I am searching for a very specific kind of record player that I couldn't find through an internet search or in stores.

I really like the look of record players, but I don't want to get into the records/vinyls themselves. I have seen some record players that allow to plug in a phone or USB stick to play digital music. As far as I understood though, there is a need to press a button to actually play the music.

What I am looking for would be something like a "dummy"-vinyl which is purely cosmetic (so I can see something spinning with the needle), and upon placing the needle on said "dummy"-vinyl the digital music from the external medium (USB stick, phone, etc.) starts playing. I'd prefer if the "record player" had an integrated speaker, but as my search hasn't been that fruitful so far, I am also happy about ones that need external speakers.

Do you know of "record players" that fit these criteria and where I could get one?

Answer (score 1):

yes there is, you do not need a special record player, but a special LP (timecode vinyl) and a software that interprets the timecodes.
Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_emulation_software